# Eight clones made by in-vitro fertilization, discovered by a female scientist

Tags: story-identification

The story is about a female scientist starting a relationship with a younger guy after meeting his criminal clone and not knowing. She investigates further to find out that they actually are eight around the world and were made by two scientists and she proceeds to uncover the truth to the world.

Comment: When did you read this? Was it a book? A short story? Online fiction? Film? TV series? Anime? Manga?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

MIght this be Ken Follett's *[The Third Twin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Third_Twin)* as per [TV show or movie about cloned soldier babies adopted by normal parents and female main character's relationship with one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/267754/tv-show-or-movie-about-cloned-soldier-babies-adopted-by-normal-parents-and-femal/267854#267854)?

It features a female associate professor and criminality researcher who befriends a student who is later arrested for a rape because his DNA matches sample found at the scene, and he's picked out of a line-up, despite him having an alibi for the time. Shortly thereafter, it's revealed that he has an identical twin who is an incarcerated criminal. It turns out that he is one of eight identical twins born as a result of an experiment in In-Vitro Fertilization to develop super-soldiers. The book calls out eight clones, it's a female researcher who finds them, and she is opposed by two scientists from the project.